# Why is my react-virtualized list not displaying scrollbar unless I make sure height is lower than rowCount*rowHeight?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using `"react-virtualized": "9.22.5"`, and I am trying to render a list.

When I pass

```
<List
  height={myList.length * 30}
  rowHeight={30}
  rowCount={myList.length}
  width={240}
  style={{maxHeight: 657}}
  rowRenderer={({ index, key, style }) => {...}
/>
```

I get only the first 21 items, even if `myList` is longer. This means that I do not get scrollbar, and that the rest of the items are not visible. If I use instead `rowCount={myList.length + 1}`, it magically counts the rows correctly and I get my scrollbar. Alternatively, setting `height={myList.length*30 - 0.001}` will also work.

`console.log(myList.length)` shows the correct length.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that `List` doesn't know what its `maxHeight` is - it "thinks" that it is displayed at full height. And since `height` is just as big as `rowCount` requires, no scrollbar is displayed. To display scollbar, `height` must be *less* than `rowCount*rowHeight`, regardless of other styles.

My solution was to write `List` without the `maxHeight`, but otherwise I would have used the `-0.001` hack.